# JAXB element context while unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to know element context in time of unmarshalling additional to XmlAdapter's ValueType and BoundType.
I need to parse some attribute representing XPath 2.0 expression and I need to collect namespace context for it's execution.

Is there a way that JAXB will return me DOM Node as context of unmarshalling as additional information?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question corretly but it is not possible to get a DOM not as a context from JAXB. The reason is that JAXB has nothing to do with DOM (at least it is not the same).

I don't know if that helps you but you can create a JAXBContext for a specific class by writing:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(YourClass.class);
```

Comment: I do that, but when unmarshalling some custom class out of field I use XMLAdapter and I don't have enough information to construct object. Jaxb returns string which is value of attribute, but I also need reference to element where this attribute is located.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think that this is possible... You probably need to set the values you need from the parent element, later on.